# Filebeat fails to start as docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, filebeat

Following is the docker-compose used.

```yaml
version: '3.5'
services:
  filebeat: 
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:6.4.2
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml:ro
      - ${PWD}/test/input:/tmp/input:rw
```

Filebeat configuration in filebeat.yml is

```yaml
filebeat.inputs:
- type: container
  paths: 
    - '/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log'

processors:
- add_docker_metadata:
    host: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

- decode_json_fields:
    fields: ["message"]
    target: "json"
    overwrite_keys: true

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
  indices:
    - index: "filebeat-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"

logging.json: true
logging.metrics.enabled: false
```

Upon `docker-compose up`, container fails start and the below mentioned error is reported.

*Exiting: error loading config file: config file ("filebeat.yml") must be owned by the user identifier (uid=0) or root*

What is the catch here? I am running this sample on my laptop running ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> error loading config file: config file ("filebeat.yml") must be owned
> by the user identifier (uid=0) or root

Generally, we start filebeat as root (to make sure that all files of the system be accessible by it).
You could try to start the filebeat service of your compose as root :

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  filebeat: 
    user: root #change here
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:6.4.2
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml:ro
      - ${PWD}/test/input:/tmp/input:rw
```

If that is not enough, you could run the container with the    `-strict.perms=false` argument that disables the permission checks such as :

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  filebeat: 
    user: root #change here
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:6.4.2
    command:
      - "-e"
      - "--strict.perms=false"
     ...
```

PS : the `-e` flag disables syslog/file output and redirects all output in the std error (not related to your point, but generally desirable in a container to read filebeat logs from the container logs).

[More info on the official site](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/running-on-docker.html).

Comment: Thanks. This works. I missed the --strict-perms=false in the documentation.